# insert() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i have made 2 diffrent codes in 2 diffrent files the first one is

and i imported this file in another file and tried ti execute it with value but its showing insert takes 2 positional argument but 1 was given.
the file in which i imported this is as follows

i am comparetively new to this stuff and i need it for my school project will any one plz help me to figure out the error in the code ... thanks

```
from tkinter import *

class Gtn:
    def insert(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.val = val
        val= str(value.get())
        print(val)


from tkinter import *
from gt_ent import Gtn as g

wn = Tk()

e = Entry(wn)
e.pack(anchor ='nw')

b= Button(wn, text='lets see ', command = lambda: g.insert(e)).pack(anchor ='nw')
```

Comment: You're calling Gtn.insert with a single argument instead of two. Since it's a static call, no instance is provided for `self`. you need to pass both an instance (`self`) and a value (`value`).

Comment: i tried ur way but its showing self is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to call a method is to instantiate the object and then call the method from the instance:

```
from gt_ent import Gtn
...
g = Gtn()
b = Button(..., command=lambda: g.insert(e))
```

Comment: thanks its ... yoo hoo .. i was hung up over this for so long